# failing to overload operator<< (c++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload << . No luck so far.
Here's my overload implementation:

```
struct Engineer{
    int id;
    int salary;
    bool hired;
public:
    Engineer(int _id, int _salary) : id(_id), salary(_salary), hired(false) {}

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os)
    {
      return os << " " << id << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and here's me trying to use it:

```
void inorderTravel(AvlNode* root) {
    if(root == NULL) return;
    inorderTravel(root->left);
    std::cout << root->data;     // <- here
    inorderTravel(root->right);
}
```

the line "std::cout << root->data;" evokes all the errors:

```
> Multiple markers at this line
>   - cannot convert 'root->AvlTree<Engineer,    IdKey>::AvlNode::data' (type 'Engineer') to type 'unsigned char'
>   - cannot convert 'root->AvlTree<Engineer,    IdKey>::AvlNode::data' (type 'Engineer') to type 'signed char'
>   - 'Engineer' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT,    _Traits, _Alloc>'
>   - cannot convert 'root->AvlTree<Engineer,    IdKey>::AvlNode::data' (type 'Engineer') to type 'char'
>   - deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' and       'Engineer')
>   - no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka    std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Engineer')
>   - candidates are:
>   - cannot convert 'root->AvlTree<Engineer,    IdKey>::AvlNode::data' (type 'Engineer') to type 'const char*'
>   - mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'Engineer'
>   - cannot convert 'root->AvlTree<Engineer,    IdKey>::AvlNode::data' (type 'Engineer') to type 'const unsigned char*'
>   - cannot convert 'root->AvlTree<Engineer,    IdKey>::AvlNode::data' (type 'Engineer') to type 'const signed char*'
```

Comment: What is the definition of `AvlNode`?

Comment: What is `root->data`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2):

You defined the operator `std::ostream& Engineer::operator<<(std::ostream&)` - so the left operand of an expression like `left << right` must be of type `Engineer` and the right operand of type `std::ostream&`...

You can define the right operator as a friend function in your `Engineer` class like so:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Engineer const& self)
{ return out << " " << self.id << std::endl; }
```

Comment: *left argument* seems a little bit misleading

Comment: @Wolf clarified the meaning

Comment: What about changing the order: Solution first, details about the failing approach later? I find that the focus lies to much on the wrong thing in the [current version of answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23325060/2).

Comment: @Wolf There are a great many discussions of how to properly overload the streaming operators already out there. Therefore the explanation of what fails about the OPs attempt seems more important to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct definition of `operator<<`. This operator should take as **second** argument a const reference to an instance of the class you are trying to print. Using your definition there is an implicit **first** argument. An `operator<<` can not be defined in a class, typically it is implemented as a friend function. Something like this:

```
struct Engineer{
  //... other code
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Engineer& e);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Engineer& e)
{
  return os << " " << id << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *An operator<< can not be defined in a class* - is this the whole truth? And, if yes, why?

Comment: @wolf From OP's question the idea is to use `operator<<` to output to a stream. If that is what is needed, the operator should be declared in the way I describe. This means that the first argument of this operator should be an `ostream&` and as all class methods have an implicit first argument of the class type it is not possible to declare such method within the class. An `operator<<` with other operand types can still be declared but it will not be used in the case OP describes.